# Singleton Not working in Spring Latest version

Tags: java, spring

I tried to set singleton as false or true in the configuration xml file as below

while validating it is throwing the below error

cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'singleton' is not allowed to appear in element 'bean'.

i am using spring version 4. Is there any other way to implement this property?

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Binil Kuriachan

Comment: Did you instead try setting `scope as singleton`?

Comment: Hi Swapnil, i tried just now and by using "scope",it is working. i started learning spring two days back only and in my reference docs, singleton was shown working. Could you please tell me whether singleton is obsolete in latest version? Similar thing exist for "dependecy-check" as well.  Thanks in advance, Binil

Comment: I've added this as an answer, please accept for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `singleton` attribute was removed in favour of `scope` attribute. As mentioned in the comment below the question, try setting the `scope` to singleton.